# How to access Quickbooks Invoice Line Items using php api

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

am trying to access the line items of the invoice in quickbooks using php api,

so that i could do some manipulations on it.....

am able to get the invoice data when i do this...

```
<?php
$Invoice = $InvoiceService->findById($Context, $realmID, $InvoiceID);
pr($Invoice);
?>
```

the result is obtained as follows

```
QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [Id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => {QBO-52}
                )

            [SyncToken] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13
                )

            [MetaData] => Array
                (
                    [0] => QuickBooks_IPP_Object_MetaData Object
                        (
                            [_data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [CreateTime] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 2013-04-02T02:55:30-07:00
                                        )

                                    [LastUpdatedTime] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 2013-04-03T04:15:53-07:00
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [Header] => Array
                (
                    [0] => QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Header Object
                        (
                            [_data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [TxnDate] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 2013-03-31-07:00
                                        )

                                    [Msg] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Customer Message update via QB++
                                        )

                                    [CustomerId] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => {QBO-35}
                                        )

                                    [SubTotalAmt] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 15.00
                                        )

                                    [TotalAmt] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 15.00
                                        )

                                    [ToBePrinted] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => false
                                        )

                                    [ToBeEmailed] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => false
                                        )

                                    [DueDate] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 2013-04-29-07:00
                                        )

                                    [BillAddr] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr Object
                                                (
                                                    [_data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Line1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Jeffery
                                                                )

                                                            [Line2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Ads India
                                                                )

                                                            [Line3] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Jeffery trading Co Ltd
                                                                )

                                                            [Line4] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Cochin
                                                                )

                                                            [Line5] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Kerala
India
                                                                )

                                                            [GeoCode] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => INVALID
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [ShipAddr] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => QuickBooks_IPP_Object_ShipAddr Object
                                                (
                                                    [_data:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Line1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Jeffery
                                                                )

                                                            [Line2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Jeffery trading Co Ltd\\nJeffery traders\\nCochin\\nIndia
                                                                )

                                                            [Line3] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Jeffery
                                                                )

                                                            [Line4] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 0484232425
                                                                )

                                                            [PostalCode] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 0
                                                                )

                                                            [GeoCode] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => INVALID
                                                                )

                                                            [Tag] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => CUSTOMER
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [ShipMethodId] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => {QBO-}
                                        )

                                    [Balance] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 15.00
                                        )

                                    [DiscountTaxable] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => true
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [Line] => Array
                (
                    [0] => QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line Object
                        (
                            [_data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [Desc] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => TES15++
                                        )

                                    [Amount] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 15.00
                                        )

                                    [Taxable] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => false
                                        )

                                    [ItemId] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => {QBO-30}
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line Object
                        (
                            [_data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 0.00
                                        )

                                    [Taxable] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => false
                                        )

                                    [ItemId] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => {QBO-21}
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I can get invoice Id, customer Id respectivly as follows

```
<?php

pr($Invoice->getId());

pr($Invoice->getHeader()->getCustomerId());

?>
```

**My question is how do i get the count of Line items and extract it to a normal array**

I tired `pr($Invoice->getLine());` it doesnt give me the whole array but just the 1st item in that array...

am finding it difficult to achieve this ....

Comment: Stop putting my name in your questions - my name has *nothing* to do with the question, and therefore shouldn't be part of the question. You're going to get yourself banned if you keep doing that.

Comment: sorry for that...it was just to inform that am using your php api...

Comment: No worries - just put "QuickBooks PHP DevKit" or something instead.

Comment: @Keith Palmer  : i have one more question how do i remove a Line item from invoice currently am able to add and edit invoice items but no found a way to remove or delete a Line Item......

Comment: You should be able to do a $Invoice->unsetLine($i); and the update the invoice.

Comment: That did it....thankyou very much...i just wonder if there is anyplace where you keep the list of functions that can be used or is supported so that we can lookup into it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Invoice->getLine(0);
$Invoice->getLine(1);
$Invoice->getLine(2);
$Invoice->getLine(3);
etc.
```

OR

```
$count = $Invoice->countLine();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
  $Line = $Invoice->getLine($i);
}
```