# How to remove lines from an Invoice using 'consolibyte/quickbooks-php'

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Is there a way to remove lines from an invoice using the Consolibyte quickbooks toolkit?

I can send invoices with lines but I would also like to update an invoice and I think the best way would be to remove each line and then send up the lines as they are currently. i.e: To update an invoice I would first get the invoice from quickbooks using the ref I store locally, remove the lines, then update the fields on the invoice object, then add the new lines and then send the invoice using the update method.

I have seen this example:

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_update.php

But I am unsure how I could update individual lines as I have no reference to them stored locally, hence trying to remove them and then re-create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here:

[How to access Quickbooks Invoice Line Items using php api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786681/how-to-access-quickbooks-invoice-line-items-using-php-api)

My solution looks like this, using Laravel:

```
public function qbUpdateInvoice(Invoice $invoice)
{
    if ($invoice->qb_ref == null) {
        throw new \Exception('Invoice Quickbooks ref not available.');
    }

    $qbInvoice = $this->findInvoiceByRef($invoice);

    $count = $qbInvoice->countLine();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $qbInvoice->unsetLine($i);
    }

    $qbInvoice = $this->setInvoiceDetails($invoice, $qbInvoice);
    $qbInvoice = $this->setInvoiceLines($invoice, $qbInvoice);

    $response = $this->qbInvoiceService->update($this->context, $this->realm, $qbInvoice->getId(), $qbInvoice);

    if (!$response) {
        throw new \Exception($this->qbInvoiceService->lastError());
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I'm about to attempt to implement this using Consolibyte with Laravel as well, did this solution work for you? Are the unsetLine and findInvoiceByRef functions a part of the Consolibyte toolkit or functions that you wrote?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't recommend the Consolibyte toolkit as it has bugs in it and you have to hack the toolkit to get it working. It also uses deprecated functions which will stop working if you upgrade to PHP7. You also can't get it to work directly with the Laravel DB connection. You have to create a separate DB connection as it only accepts DSN's and doesn't support PDO. I ended up going with the official toolkit from Quickbooks which also isn't perfect. It's a little bit more difficult to set up but much more flexible.